# Missing application resource while running script in pyspark

Tags: python, cassandra, cron, pyspark, ipython

I have been trying to execute a script .py by pyspark but I keep getting this error:

```
11:55 $ ./bin/spark-submit --jars spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar --py-files example.py
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

I can easily execute it by doing this:

```
 11:57 $  pyspark --jars spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar
```

then paste the code block by block in the `IPython` (interactive shell) . but I want to put the script in a cronjob so that It can be executed automatically. I need a command to put in cronjob and the `spark-submit` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the jar in your current directory or anywhere else on your path?

Comment: @Prathik Helloo my question was asked before !!

Answer (score 7):

you need to put the python file at the end again.

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar --py-files example.py example.py
```

Comment: "The spark-submit command actually expects a jar file as the last argument which holds the compiled code. eg. spark-submit --jars spark-nlp.jar --class Main app.jar"    https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues/35